What is the exact vocab size of the Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407 tokenizer model?
From the docs, it's

Vocabulary size: 2**17 ~= 128k

But what is the exact vocab size of the Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407 tokenizer model?

Each standard tokenizer has a property called vocab_size and __len__ can also be used to get the size of the supported vocabulary. The vocabulary is also available as a dictionary via vocab.
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

secret = 'hf_...'
t = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("mistralai/Mistral-Nemo-Instruct-2407", token=secret)

print(t.vocab_size)
print(len(t))
print(len(t.vocab))

Output:
131072
131072
131072


Thanks! I found it rather odd that the mistral_common didn't have the vocab access

They have, it is just a bit hidden: tokenizer.instruct_tokenizer.tokenizer.n_words or to access the vocab: tokenizer.instruct_tokenizer.tokenizer.vocab()

Ah nice, it's 3-4 nested layers inside, I gave up at 2.
